# Sort by a.text value

Tags: jquery, html, css, sorting

I have this markup

```
<div id="aercology">
    <div class="row shaded">
      <div class="columns one">
       <span><a href="#">Gema</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="columns two">
       <span><a href="#">Air Quality<br>Engineering(AQE)</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="columns three">
       <span><a href="#">Whitney</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="columns one">
       <span><a href="#">Guyson</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="columns two">
       <span><a href="#">Hoffman</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="columns three">
       <span><a href="#">Micro Air</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how do i use jquery to sort the text in alphabetical order.
retaining the class shaded on the div row.??
div row goes through alternately..

current code

```
var mylist = jQuery('#aercology');

                var listitems = mylist.children('.columns span a').get();

                listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
                   return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(jQuery(b).text().toUpperCase());
                });

                jQuery.each(listitems, function(index, item) {
                   mylist.append(item); 
                });
```

desired output would be

```
<div id="aercology">
    <div class="row shaded">
      <div class="columns one">
       <span><a href="#">Air Quality<br>Engineering(AQE)</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="columns two">
      <span><a href="#">Gema</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="columns three">
       <span><a href="#">Guyson</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="columns one">
        <span><a href="#">Hoffman</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="columns two">
        <span><a href="#">Micro Air</a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="columns three">
      <span><a href="#">Whitney</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: you want to sort each row separately?

Comment: Sorry, But I don't get your Message.

Comment: no.. sort all rows..

Comment: have you tried anything yet?...

Comment: which column do you want it to be sorted? I mean, sort all rows by what column?

Comment: this might help you... http://jsfiddle.net/88L8kLzb/

Comment: why do you want to do it in jquery? Isn't this some data retrieved from server side. You can always sort the data in the database query and return sorted results...

Comment: its not fetched from the server its a static HTML with that markup.
But its a long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var items = $('.row a').map(function () {
  return $(this).html();
}).get();

items.sort().reverse();

$(".row a").each(function(){
  $(this).html(items.pop())
})
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ec3y7m20/2/)

Comment: this one solves it and to retain the <br/> in the text ive change it to html var items = $('.row a').map(function () {
     return $(this).html();
   }).get();
    items.sort().reverse();
    $(".row a").each(function(){
     $(this).html(items.pop())
    });
   });

Comment: @rrapuya yea i updated it... would be nice of you to accept the answer if it helped.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick fiddle, [see here.](http://jsfiddle.net/t29o0r3j/1/)

Is that what you're trying to do?

**HTML**

```
 <div id="aercology">
  <div class="rowshaded">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Gema</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Air Quality Engineering(AQE)</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Whitney</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Micro Air</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Guyson</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Hoffman</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.rowshaded li').sort(function(a, b){
return $('a', a).text() > $('a', b).text() 
}).appendTo('div.rowshaded')

$('.row li').sort(function(a, b){
return $('a', a).text() > $('a', b).text() 
}).appendTo('div.row')
```

Comment: THE HTML MARKUP USED IN YOUR EXAMPLE IS NOT MATCHING FROM THE QUESTION. THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER BUT ASSISTANCE.